# Include missing month and data in entity framework core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get data by group by month. it returns if the month exists. I need to return the missing month data as 0.

my code

```
var res = await fetchQuery.GroupBy(da => new { da.EmployeeJoinedDate.Month, da.DepartmentId, }).Select(g => new EmployeeCount
                {
                    Period = g.Key.Month,
                    DepartmentId = g.Key.DepartmentId,
                    EmployeeCount = g.Select(EmployeeId).Distinct().Count()
                }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: What do you mean missing month data? If all employees joined on October, you would only have one grouping for October.

Comment: ex: if data exists in October and december above query returns
{{
   Period = 10,
  Count = 2
},
{
  Period = 12,
Count = 1
}
]

i need period(month) 11 also

Comment: @trashr0x {{ Period = 10, Count = 2 }, { Period = 11, Count = 0 }, { Period = 12, Count = 1 } ] i want result like this

Comment: Then you need to have some static "Months" table (or list) and left join on your results.

Comment: @trashr0x I have to group the data by year, month, and quarter. Also, the request date range is dynamic. the fincial year start from may to apr